# How to use unicode characters with PIL?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, python-imaging-library

I would like to add Russian text to the image. I use PIL 1.1.7 and Python 2.7 on Windows machine. Since PIL compiled [without libfreetype library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4011715/604388), I use the following on development server:

```
font_text = ImageFont.load('helvR24.pil')
draw.text((0, 0), 'Текст на русском', font=font_text)
```

(`helvR24.pil` is taken from http://effbot.org/media/downloads/pilfonts.zip)

On Production environment I do the following:

```
font_text = ImageFont.truetype('HelveticaRegular.ttf', 24, encoding="utf-8")
draw.text((0, 0), 'Текст на русском', font=font_text)
```

(tried to use `unic`, `cp-1251` instead of `utf-8`)

In both cases it doesn't display Russian characters ('squares' or dummy characters are displayed instead). I think it doesn't work on Development environment since most probably `helvR24.pil` doesn't contain Russian characters (don't know how to check it). But `HelveticaRegular.ttf` surely has it. I also checked that my `.py` file has геа-8 encoding. And it doesn't display Russian characters even with default font:

```
draw.text((0, 0), 'Текст на русском', font=ImageFont.load_default())
```

What else should I try / verify? I've looked thru https://stackoverflow.com/a/18729512/604388 - it doesn't help.

Comment: try to pass the text as unicode string: `draw.text((0, 0), u'Текст на русском', font=ImageFont.load_default())`

Comment: @mata, surely I've tried that already (as well as `unicode('Текст на русском', 'utf-8')`). It returns `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)` referring to `PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 267, text mask = font.getmask(text, self.fontmode)`.

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar issue and solved it.

There are a couple things you have to be careful about:

1. Ensure that your strings are interpreted as unicode, either by
   importing unicode_literarls from _____future_____ or by prepending the u
   to your strings
2. Ensure you are using a font that is unicode,there are some free
   here: [open-source unicode typefaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_Unicode_typefaces) I suggest this: [dejavu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dejavu/)

here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFilter

#configuration
font_size=36
width=500
height=100
back_ground_color=(255,255,255)
font_size=36
font_color=(0,0,0)
unicode_text = u"\u2605" + u"\u2606" + u"Текст на русском"

im  =  Image.new ( "RGB", (width,height), back_ground_color )
draw  =  ImageDraw.Draw ( im )
unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("DejaVuSans.ttf", font_size)
draw.text ( (10,10), unicode_text, font=unicode_font, fill=font_color )

im.save("text.jpg")
```

here is the results

[image]

Comment: I've created a [script that draws all Unicode characters based on your answer](https://gist.github.com/zed/07a8175ba07f393a6004/83e59f794e9d746384e2c23fda4aad959730a104#file-text2image-py)

Answer (score 4):

Can you examine your TTF file? I suspect that it doesn't support the characters you want to draw.

On my computer (Ubuntu 13.04), this sequence produces the correct image:

```
ttf=ImageFont.truetype('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf', 16)

im = Image.new("RGB", (512,512), "white")
ImageDraw.Draw(im).text((00,00), u'Текст на русском', fill='black', font=ttf)

im.show()
```

N.b. When I didn't specify unicode (`u'...'`), the result was [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).