# Sphinx and blockdiag: non-English characters give UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have an RST file to compile with Sphinx.

I have a block diagram there.

I want to give non-english names to some of its nodes.

```
.. blockdiag::

   diagram {
     "UberMega" -> "HellSotona" -> "KakoDemon" -> "Кролики и котятки";
   }
```

Alas, it gives me an error:

```
  File "C:\Python2\lib\site-packages\blockdiag\imagedraw\png.py", line 282, in textlinesize
    size = self.draw.textsize(string, font=None)
  File "C:\Python2\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 282, in textsize
    return font.getsize(text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(256)
WARNING: blockdiag error: UnicodeEncodeError caught (check your font settings)
```

How can I cope with it?

Comment: The error originates in PIL/Pillow's ImageDraw.py module, and I think this question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18942605/407651. I have no solution to your problem, however.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in python 2 aren't unicode by default.  Try this:

```
.. blockdiag::

diagram {
 "UberMega" -> "HellSotona" -> "KakoDemon" -> u"Кролики и котятки";
}
```

Comment: I've tried. Nothing changes. It looks like blockdiag doesn't eat u'' marker.

Comment: Gives an Error:

C:\Projects\PAT\PyPhased\docs\simple_pulse_radar.rst:6: WARNING: undecodable source characters, replacing with "?": '     "Rectangular Waveform" -> "Transmitter" -> "Radiator" -> "Free Space" -> "Target" -> unicode("\xca\xf0\xee\xeb\xe8\xea>>>\xe8<<<");'
C:\Projects\PAT\PyPhased\docs\simple_pulse_radar.rst:3: WARNING: Got unexpected token at line 2 column 95

Comment: What if you add this to the top of the file? '# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-'.  May need to add it to conf.py also/instead

Edit: There is one asterisk in the middle of each set of dashes, i don't know why its not showing

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same problem. Looks like you're using it in sphinx documentation.

You should point to your unicode TrueType font (put it in `_static` directory, i've chosen a DejaVuSans. No reasons, it's just easy to find over Internet). Copy your `.ttf` file to static directory and add this lines to `conf.py`:

```
import os
blockdiag_fontpath = os.path.abspath(u'_static/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf')
```

Note the `u` mark before the relative path. Blockdiag ignores this if the path to your project includes any non-ASCII characters and the path is not a unicode string.