# How to draw Chinese text on the title of image using cv2.imshow(title,image correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I try to use python OpenCV (Windows 10, Python 3.6) to write title in image, when the text is English it works, but when I use Chinese **title**, it was out of order.

Below is my code:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # open webcam

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()  # 读Read the camera picture
    cv2.imshow('中文', frame)  # reveal 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  # 
        break

cap.release()  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When title = "English"   # **just work**, below is the output image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNunT.png)

When title = "中文"   # **doesn't work**, below is the output image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70FE7.png)

What I have tried adding encode('utf-8') or gbk to the title and then decoding it with errors='ignore', but it doesn't work, the title is still garbled.

I currently know that PIL can solve the problem of Chinese garbled characters in cv2.imshow's **put text** from [How to draw Chinese text on the image using `cv2.putText`correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854235/how-to-draw-chinese-text-on-the-image-using-cv2-puttextcorrectly-pythonopen?newreg=ce69b40957ef42bdacf2c5dfc6c6ba7e), but I don't know how to solve the title problem, and i think they are **different**.

Comment: You can use matplotlib, which is able to create windows with utf8 title. Example code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44604435/18667225