# Showing Square instead of Some Special characters - Python PIL

Tags: python, discord, python-imaging-library

I've tried many many things but it didn't fix my problem.
what I've tried: changing Font, saving the file as UTF-8, etc...
my code:

```py
    img = Image.open("WlcImageThings/bg.png")
    txtUser_font = ImageFont.truetype('WlcImageThings/DejaVuSans.ttf', 25)
    eimg = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    eimg.text((25,50), u'', (237, 230, 211), font=txtUser_font, stroke_width=2, stroke_fill=(0, 0, 0))
    img.save("WlcImageThings/result.png", quality=100)
    file = discord.File("WlcImageThings/result.png", filename="result.png")
    await channel.send(file=file)
```

result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhWaC.png)

Comment: And what is your problem?  You haven't really asked a question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use unicode characters with PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942605/how-to-use-unicode-characters-with-pil)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I see now.  The problem is that DejaVuSans does not contain those code points.  I tried other Unicode code points (like the line drawing set), and those work fine.  You will need to find a font that includes those characters.

Comment: The question is a little misleading in that it uses code points that look *a lot* like regular ASCII characters.  The actual string is `'\U0001d5fa\U0001d5ee\U0001d5f1'`.

Comment: Yes, it took me way too long to figure that out.  ;)

Comment: Don't feel bad, I didn't figure it out either until I saw your answer.  Luckily I have a function to grab the actual Unicode from the clipboard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678113/5987

Comment: hi, cuz it's for a Discord Welcome Bot, some users may use different fonts and symbols on their names. is there any font to show all characters?

Comment: No.  There are fonts that include MANY Unicode code points (Code2000, Arial Unicode), but since emojis change so often, they don't keep up.