# using pillow to make a rank card in discord, but it can't write the name properly for some users

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-imaging-library

```
txt3 = f"{str(member.name)}"
font3 = ImageFont.truetype("./font/arial.ttf", fontsize3)
draw.text((35,35), txt3, font=font3, fill=(255, 255, 255))
```

Alright, so here is the issue. The above works fine, like it should. Here is a scenario where the code is used for people with a normal name:

[image]

So, that's all good. However when I use the command on a user with a unique/fancy name, it throws this at me.

[image]

It's just throwing boxes. I was trying to imitate an API for rank cards. The thing is that, the API also uses `arial` (I asked the API's owner) but it can show the name correctly while when using PIL, it fails. Thus I believe the issue is with PIL and not the font I am using.
Is there any way I can fix this. (For reference purpose, I will put the image made using the API call below)

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Unicode characters not rendering with PIL ImageFont](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729148/unicode-characters-not-rendering-with-pil-imagefont)

Comment: Issue could also be that during script execution the unicode character information is lost. PIL might work but it fails beforehand. I'd log out the string a couple of times during code and see if it gets displayed there properly.

Comment: `txt3.decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a Unicode font for that. For example **Arial Unicode MS**.

**With Arial:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWSBO.png

**With Arial Unicode:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfvXP.png